# Can I set multiple variables value in single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server. I have 5 variables: `@contentsType, @itemIDand, @dealerID, @userID,@itemID`

How can I set these variables values in single this query once?

```
SET @contentsType = (select top 1 mi.type_id from #tempResults as tr left join [myDB].[dbo].myTable mi on tr.item_id = mi.id)
SET @itemID = (select top 1 mi.item_id from #tempResults as tr left join [myDB].[dbo].myTable mi on tr.item_id = mi.id)
SET @dealerID = (select top 1 mi.dealer_id from #tempResults as tr left join [myDB].[dbo].myTable mi on tr.item_id = mi.id)
SET @userID = (select top 1 mi.user_id from #tempResults as tr left join [myDB].[dbo].myTable mi on tr.item_id = mi.id)
SET @itemID = (select top 1 id from #tempResults)
```

Comment: not sure i understand what you are trying to do. do you expect more than 1 row from your queries?

Comment: You shouldn't use `top` without `order by`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `select set`

```
select top 1
    @contentsType = mi.type_id,
    @itemID = mi.item_id,
    @dealerID = mi.dealer_id,
    @userID = mi.user_id
from #tempResults as tr
left join [myDB].[dbo].myTable mi on tr.item_id = mi.id;

select top 1 @itemID = id from #tempResults
```